# Minimum of two uint64 series with missing values without float64 conversion

Tags: python, pandas

I have a types conundrum:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series([5, 3, 5], index=[1, 3, 4])  # int64
b = pd.Series([1, 9, 4], index=[1, 2, 4])  # int64

m = pd.DataFrame([a, b]).min()             # float64
```

I know exactly why it happens: once I put `a` and `b` in the same dataframe, there are missing values, and missing values can't be represented in `int64`, so the dtype is bumped up to `float64`. But I'd really like to get that minimum without the conversion. Is there a way to pre-fill-in the missing values from the other column, or any other technique that would let me take the minimum of the two series without having to deal with `NaN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) of both `indexes`, parameter `fill_value` replace `NaN` to some scalar. You need `min`, so one possible solution is some huge `int` like `10000` or `max` of `Series`:

```
idx = b.index.union(a.index)

print (pd.DataFrame([a.reindex(idx, fill_value=a.max()), 
                     b.reindex(idx, fill_value=b.max())]))

   1  2  3  4
0  5  5  3  5
1  1  9  9  4

m = pd.DataFrame([a.reindex(idx, fill_value=a.max()), 
                  b.reindex(idx, fill_value=b.max())]).min()
print (m)
1    1
2    5
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yeah, this looks exactly like what I wanted. Probably premature optimisation; but I'm still learning to think in Pandas.